# Tensorflow ResizeBilinear gives different results than cv::resize

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow

I am doing some experiments with tensorflow/classify_image.py with `InceptionV3` and noted that `ResizeBilinear` operation gives different results than cv::resize. Even though they both seem to be using Bilinear Filtering but I wonder why their output is completely different.

These are the layers present in the `InceptionV3` network.

```
<tf.Tensor 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0' shape=() dtype=string>,
<tf.Tensor 'DecodeJpeg:0' shape=(?, ?, 3) dtype=uint8>,
<tf.Tensor 'Cast:0' shape=(?, ?, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims/dim:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(1, ?, ?, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ResizeBilinear/size:0' shape=(2,) dtype=int32>,
<tf.Tensor 'ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(1, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Sub/y:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Sub:0' shape=(1, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Mul/y:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'Mul:0' shape=(1, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>,
```

Instead of feeding into the first operation, I am reading the image using cv::imread and feeding it into `DecodeJpeg:0`

```
img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = img[..., ::-1]
resize_bilinear = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('ResizeBilinear:0')
resize_img1 = sess.run(resize_bilinear, {'DecodeJpeg:0': img})


img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img = img[..., ::-1]
resize_img2 = cv2.resize(img, (299, 299))
```

When I compare, resize_img1 and resize_img2, they are completely different. Anyone has any idea what's going wrong?

Any leads will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I met the same problem...

Comment: OpenCV keeps them as `uint8` while TF converts the images to `float` images. From the [TF image guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_guides/python/image#Resizing): "The resizing Ops accept input images as tensors of several types. They always output resized images as `float32` tensors."